# Viewshed analysis with random configuration of observer points and getting the best configuration in terms of visibility?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I have a clipped raster image and observer points (4 points) to be placed on the raster image. I have to perform the viewshed analysis but I want ArcMap to place the points with random configuration and give results for each configuration so we can select the best configuration in terms of maximum visibity.
I have selected 6 observer points and want to perform viewshed analysis. The result is shown in the figure. Now in the second figure I have changed the observer points places so the results I get are different. What I want is that ArcMap should place these points in such a way that we can get the maximum visibility from those six observer points.

[image]

Comment: Random search will give you nothing, because number of combinations for tiny raster made of 100 cells you are looking at 3.6M combinations.

Comment: Actually my question is that i am having DEM and I would like to do a viewshed analysis. But instead of me using existing points to determine the viewshed, I would like to find all points where the entire state would be covered by a viewshed.

So for example, I want to find suitable locations for antenna placements. Instead of me just guessing trying to figure out which location would give me the best results, I would like the GIS to optimally find points where the entire state would be covered with antenna coverage.is it possible?

Comment: Assuming that an optimal placement for an antenna would be at the "top of a mountain", your workflow would probably have to look at min/max of the DEM values, take a slice of the max values, perform the viewshed on those in a loop, but also possibly throwing out values that are too close to one another. You tag `modelbuilder`, but this sounds like a `Python` / `arcpy` workflow.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain your commented explanation of your task. you should also provide information on what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: Even using local maxima, this has the hallmarks of an NP problem, possibly NP-Hard, and depending on the requirements, possibly NP-Complete. While random pool selection can sometimes help in such cases, it can also hurt.